# I'm trying to make a list of all the posts classified under one term for a custom taxonomy.

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, archive, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to make a list of all the posts classified under one term for a custom taxonomy.

I have created a custom post type called "testimonial" with a custom taxonomy of "testimonial categories". with in testimonial categories I have created the terms "colleagues" and "clients".
I am trying to create too archive pages. One that will list all of the posts under colleagues and the other list all posts under clients.
I have created the archive pages taxonomy-testimonial_categories-clients.php and taxonomy-testimonial_categories-colleagues.php. And can creat a list of all post under the cpt testimonials but can't filter it by the terms Colleagues or clients.

After research on wordpress.org I believe that using  tax_query with new WP_Query is the way to go.
Here is the code I'm working with now.

```
 <?php           

 $args = array(
'post_type' => 'testimonial',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'testimonial_categories',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'colleagues'
    )
)
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();    ?>
<span class="frame small alignleft">                 
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(thumbnail); ?>   
            <span>                                           
          <div class="test-content">                                                                                    
        <?php the_content(); ?>                                         
            </div>   
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although its way too late here is the only solution that worked for me,

```
$my_taxonomy_name = "your taxo. name";
$my_term_name = "your term name";
$my_term_id = -1;

$terms = get_terms($my_taxonomy_name);

if(count($terms)>0){
     foreach ($terms as $term) {
       if($term->name == $my_term_name){
           $term_id=$term->term_id;
           continue;
       }        
     }
$my_posts = array();
$postids_in_term = get_objects_in_term($term_id,'ad_setting'); 
foreach($postids_in_term as $post_id){
    array_push($my_posts,get_post($post_id));
}

var_dump($my_posts);
}
```

In no way this is elegant, but hey, it works!